# Jenkins SSH remote hosts Can't connect to server

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can access to the target with ssh password and with the private key from Jenkins bash, I configured SSH sites on jenkins with the same host, User and private key I get the next error:

[image]

Docker logs:

```
2022-09-23 05:06:52.357+0000 [id=71]    SEVERE  o.j.h.p.SSHBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl#doLoginCheck: Auth fail 2022-09-23 05:06:52.367+0000 [id=71] SEVERE  o.j.h.p.SSHBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl#doLoginCheck: Can't connect to server
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: fedora
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - net
  db_host:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM fedora

RUN yum update -y

RUN yum -y install unzip

RUN yum -y install openssh-server

RUN useradd RemoteUser && \ 
  echo "RemoteUser:Password"| chpasswd && \
  mkdir /home/madchabelo/.ssh && \
  chmod 700 /home/madchabelo/.ssh

COPY remote-ki.pub /home/madchabelo/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown madchabelo:madchabelo -R /home/madchabelo/.ssh/ && \
  chmod 600 /home/madchabelo/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN ssh-keygen -A

RUN yum -y install mysql

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip  && \
    sudo ./aws/install

RUN yum -y install vim

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

I try with the IP and I get the same.

regards

Answer (score 0):

When creating a private key, you should create a code with the following command after version ubuntu 20.04.

ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -m PEM -f remote-key

For a more detailed explanation, see the link below:

https://community.jenkins.io/t/ssh-connection-auth-fail/4121/7